# How to use jQuery UI touch events on html web page.

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I need to use the Jquery UI touch event (swipe) for the mobile users who will visit my website.  The problem is that I don't want to change the html of my web page. I wish I could only excute the jqueryUi code once a mobile size screen is detected.

Please advice

Comment: "mobile" is not a useful term. Do you mean "has a touch screen"? [this](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Dell-XPS-15-9550-Signature-Edition-Laptop/productID.326871600) 3840x2160 pixel 15.6" screen is touch capable, so screen size isn't a useful metric for you at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute the jQ UI code when detecting mobile useragent -

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod)/) !== null) {
    // execute code here
}
```

Do note that I only included Androids and Apple products, you can extend the list to match Windows Phone as well at your will.